# Updating the table from stored procedure using openrowset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, openrowset

I am trying to update the column [IsUnique-check] in the table from stored procedure. I try following code.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spIsUnique
    @columnname NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @tablename NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC ('select IIf (count(*)>1,''False'',''True'') as [IsUnique-check] 
           from '+@tablename+' 
           group by '+@columnname)
END

DECLARE @start INT, @count INT,
        @applicableforcolumn VARCHAR(MAX),
        @name VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @start = 1

SELECT @count = COUNT(*) 
FROM dbo.fnplatformnumber23()

WHILE @start <= @count
BEGIN
    SELECT @name = name 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('fnplatformnumber23') 
      AND column_id = @start

    IF @name = 'IsUnique'
    BEGIN
        SELECT @applicableforcolumn = ApplicableForColumn
        FROM dbo.fnplatformnumber23()
        WHERE IsUnique IS NOT NULL;

        EXEC spIsUnique @applicableforcolumn,'fnproduct()'
        --declare @alter nvarchar(max)= 'alter table ##producttable add [IsUnique-check] nvarchar(max);'
        --exec sp_executesql @alter

        UPDATE ##producttable 
        SET [IsUnique-check] = EXEC spIsUnique @applicableforcolumn 'fnproduct()' from OPENROWSET('SQL Server',
    'Server=DESKTOP-JEQ4NUR\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;',

    'exec spIsUnique '+@applicableforcolumn+' ''fnproduct()'';'
)
    END

    SET @start = @start + 1
END
```

But It is saying incorrect syntax near exec.

Help me solve it

Comment: Show the `spIsUnique` proc code to understand how it returns the value

Comment: I have edit it.Please see it

Comment: `openrowset()` does not accept expression. Don't think it accept variable also. You may need to use `Dynamic SQL` to form the query and use `sp_executesql` to execute it

Comment: `Update table set column = exec astoredproc` is definitely incorrect. You need to return the value from the proc into a scalar value first

Answer (score 0):

`OPENROWSET` does not support parameter. So Instead, make your Query as a Query string and Execute Using `sp_executesql` or `EXEC`. May be Like this

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT 
    * 
    FROM OPENROWSET(''SQL Server'',
    ''Server=DESKTOP-JEQ4NUR\SQLEXPRESS;Trusted_Connection=yes;'',

    ''exec spIsUnique '''+@applicableforcolumn+''',fnproduct());'


exec(@SQL)
```

Insert a Result of the Above to a Temp table and then update your final table by joining with that temp table